# How to properly align widgets using flex property in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a footer and I want everything to appear Centered with even space between these three widgets in the below code.

```
Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Text(
                'All Right Reserved',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              )),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FooterItem(
                  title: 'Twitter',
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                FooterItem(
                  title: 'Instagram',
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                FooterItem(
                  title: 'WhatsApp',
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Text(
                'All Right Reserved',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

I tried using flex as seen in the above code but it doesn't align at the center and no even space as seen in the below screenshot. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You can also get results without the use of Flex and if you want From Flex then prefer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-flexible-widget/#:~:text=Flexible%20is%20a%20built%2Din,the%20default%20fit%20of%20FlexFit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all `Expanded` and use `mainAxisAlignment` in parent `Row`:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[]
)
```